# Products from a particular category does not affect the free shipping

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to filter products from a particular product category and these products (amount) does not affect the free shipping min amount.

So i thought i increase the min amount with the special product amount.

Example:
Free Shipping is from 40 Euro.
The Customer buys products for 35 Euro and a 6 Euro product from the spacial category. Total = 41 Euro

Normaly he gets free shipping. But not with the special product in his card.

Is this posible?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'cardNo_freeShipping', 10, 2 ); 
function cardNo_freeShipping($rates, $package){

global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart(); // Get all cart items

foreach($items as $item => $values) {       
    $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
    foreach ($terms as $term) {     
        if($term->slug == "The-Special-Category"){  //If is the special category            
            if($values['variation_id']) $price = get_post_meta($values['variation_id'] , '_price', true);   //If variation exist get price
            else $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);                            //else get singel price
            $PriceArray[] = $price * $values['quantity'];           
            }
    }
} 

//get vars
$free_shipping_settings = get_option( 'woocommerce_free_shipping_settings' );
$CartSubtotal = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal;

if($PriceArray) {
    $Sum = array_sum($PriceArray);
    //The reason it's not exactly 0 lies in the definition of floating point numbers.
    $MinAmount = intval($CartSubtotal*100) - intval($Sum*100);
    $MinAmount = $MinAmount/100;        
    //The reason it's not exactly 0 lies in the definition of floating point numbers.
}   

if(!$MinAmount){ //No Special products in cart
    // Only modify rates if free_shipping is present
    if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping'] ) ) {
        // To unset a single rate/method, do the following. This example unsets flat_rate shipping
        unset( $rates['flat_rate'] );           
        // To unset all methods except for free_shipping, do the following
        $free_shipping          = $rates['free_shipping'];
        $rates                  = array();
        $rates['free_shipping'] = $free_shipping;
        }
    }

if($MinAmount==0){ //Only special products in cart
    // Only modify rates if flat_rate is present
    if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate'] ) ) {
        unset( $rates['free_shipping'] );               
        // To unset all methods except for flat rate, do the following
        $flat_rate          = $rates['flat_rate'];
        $rates              = array();
        $rates['flat_rate'] = $flat_rate;       
        }
    }else{ //Normal and special products in cart
        if($free_shipping_settings['min_amount'] >= $MinAmount){    
            if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate'] ) ) {           
                unset( $rates['free_shipping'] );               
                // To unset all methods except for flat rate, do the following
                $flat_rate          = $rates['flat_rate'];
                $rates              = array();
                $rates['flat_rate'] = $flat_rate;
                }
            }else{
                if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping'] ) ) {
                    // To unset a single rate/method, do the following. This example unsets flat_rate shipping
                    unset( $rates['flat_rate'] );

                    // To unset all methods except for free_shipping, do the following
                    $free_shipping          = $rates['free_shipping'];
                    $rates                  = array();
                    $rates['free_shipping'] = $free_shipping;
                    }
                else if( isset( $rates['flat_rate'] ) ) {           
                    unset( $rates['free_shipping'] );               
                    // To unset all methods except for flat rate, do the following
                    $flat_rate          = $rates['flat_rate'];
                    $rates              = array();
                    $rates['flat_rate'] = $flat_rate;
                    }
                }
        }           
return $rates;
}
```

Maybe you have a better idea? Thanks ;)

Comment: what do you want to do ? explain a little.

Comment: Products of a special category in the cart does not increase the total cart amount for free shipping.

Comment: your code seems correct. what is the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure if the filter is correct...
It should happen in the shopping cart and the checkout too.

Comment: It runs about 66 percent...
There are three variations ...
1. only Special Category Products...
2. only products without the Special Category Products...
3. Both together...
2 & 3 variation seems to run. 1 makes problems

Comment: is if($MinAmount==0){  entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone need it again...

Here the right code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'cardNo_freeShipping', 10, 2 ); 
function cardNo_freeShipping($rates, $package){

global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart(); // Get all cart items

foreach($items as $item => $values) {       
    $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
    foreach ($terms as $term) {     
        if($term->slug == "xartotainies"){  //If is the special category            
            if($values['variation_id']) $price = get_post_meta($values['variation_id'] , '_price', true);   //If variation exist get price
            else $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);                            //else get singel price
            $PriceArray[] = $price * $values['quantity'];           
            }
    }
} 

//get vars
$free_shipping_settings = get_option( 'woocommerce_free_shipping_settings' );
$CartSubtotal = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal;

if($PriceArray) {
    $Sum = array_sum($PriceArray);
    //The reason it's not exactly 0 lies in the definition of floating point numbers.
    $MinAmount = intval($CartSubtotal*100) - intval($Sum*100);
    $MinAmount = $MinAmount/100;        
    //The reason it's not exactly 0 lies in the definition of floating point numbers.
    if($MinAmount==0)$MinAmount=0.1; //fix zero problem
}   

if(!$MinAmount){ //No Special products in cart
    // Only modify rates if free_shipping is present
    if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping'] ) ) {
        // To unset a single rate/method, do the following. This example unsets flat_rate shipping
        unset( $rates['flat_rate'] );           
        // To unset all methods except for free_shipping, do the following
        $free_shipping          = $rates['free_shipping'];
        $rates                  = array();
        $rates['free_shipping'] = $free_shipping;
        }           
    }else{          
        if($MinAmount >= $free_shipping_settings['min_amount']){
            if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping'] ) ) {
                // To unset a single rate/method, do the following. This example unsets flat_rate shipping
                unset( $rates['flat_rate'] );           
                // To unset all methods except for free_shipping, do the following
                $free_shipping          = $rates['free_shipping'];
                $rates                  = array();
                $rates['free_shipping'] = $free_shipping;
                }
            }else{
                if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate'] ) ) {
                    unset( $rates['free_shipping'] );               
                    // To unset all methods except for flat rate, do the following
                    $flat_rate          = $rates['flat_rate'];
                    $rates              = array();
                    $rates['flat_rate'] = $flat_rate;       
                    }
                }   

        }
return $rates;
}
```